How to get instance of attributed directive from an element dynamically in code behind
I'm wondering if there any way to get instance of a directive on DIV element?
There's lots of divs, and I would not like handle a list in component.
<div class="item"
     (click)="func($event)"
     appBoardResize>
</div>
<div class="item"
     (click)="func($event)"
     appBoardResize>
</div>

The number of divs is unlimited, and I'd like get appBoardResize instance accordingly to each div in func().
NG version:17^

please share the minimal reproducible code also explaining the expected output from the code

@NarenMurali sample code added. please treat appBoardResize  is an empty directive.

The simplest way will be to just pass the instance of the div, as a parameter to the function, for this we use exportAs on the directive and specify it on the template reference variable.
import { Component, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBoardResize]',
  exportAs: 'appBoardResize',
  standalone: true,
})
export class AppBoardResize {
  innerProp = 'test';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AppBoardResize],
  template: `
  @for(item of items;track $index) {
    <div class="item"
        #directive="appBoardResize"
        (click)="func($event, directive)"
        appBoardResize>
        some div
    </div>
    <div class="item"
        #directive="appBoardResize"
        (click)="func($event, directive)"
        appBoardResize>
        some div 2
    </div>
  }
  `,
})
export class App {
  items = new Array(10);

  func(event: Event, directive: AppBoardResize) {
    console.log(event, directive);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Another way is to use the viewChildren function of angular to fetch all the directives in the component, the array, will be available only on the ngAfterViewInit hook.
Since you are using angular 17 I am recommending the signals way, but the same thing can be done with @ViewChildren(AppBoardResize) directives!: QueryList<AppBoardResize>;
import { Component, Directive, viewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBoardResize]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class AppBoardResize {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AppBoardResize],
  template: `
  @for(item of items;track $index) {
    <div class="item"
        (click)="func($event)"
        appBoardResize>
        some div
    </div>
    <div class="item"
        (click)="func($event)"
        appBoardResize>
        some div 2
    </div>
  }
  `,
})
export class App {
  directives = viewChildren(AppBoardResize);
  items = new Array(10);

  func(event: Event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.directives());
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks, it's working greatly.
BTW, I'm wondering and can't help to ask, is there something like bellow logic we can make it easily?
func($event)
{
   //assume we have getDirective or else in angular?
   $event.element.nativeElement.getDirective(AppBoardResize);
}


@LeiChi These are my top recommendations, if you want assign the variable to a property of the component and use the property inside the function instead
(click)="tempVar = directive;func($event)"

That's good, upvoted, and will have another try.
